# Webkul Layerednavigation

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation, list.phtml

I just installed Magento 2 webkul advanced layered navigation. but wen I use it as composer, I get below error:

> [RuntimeException]
>     Source class "\Webkul\AdvancedLayeredNavigation" for "\Webkul\AdvancedL
>     ayeredNavigation\Logger" generation does not exist.

This is my **composer.json:**

```
{
"name": "webkul/navigation",
"description": "Advanced Layered Navigation For Magento2",
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "2.0.2",
"license": [
    "proprietary"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Webkul\\AdvancedLayeredNavigation\\": "src/app/code/Webkul/AdvancedLayeredNavigation"
    }
}
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: There are better products in the market. Go for premium extension providers like Amasty or Aheadworks.

Comment: I have this one right now! could you please help me for this issue?